# SOAP MalformedURIException with character ^

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

I have to call a webservice with SOAP that happens to have a `^` in the URL. The URL has this structure

```
String url = "http://sampleurl.com?type=entry&version=1.0&Sender.Service=SenderService&Interface=sampleurl/ABC^ServiceRequest";
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI$MalformedURIException: Query string contains invalid character:^
11:47:10,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI.initializePath(JaxmURI.java:690)
11:47:10,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI.initialize(JaxmURI.java:407)
11:47:10,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI.<init>(JaxmURI.java:194)
11:47:10,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI.<init>(JaxmURI.java:178)
11:47:10,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:254)
```

The thing that puzzle me out is that calling the webservice with SOAP UI gives me a correct answer even if I put the `^` in the URL.

If I scape the caret character to `%5e` in my application or in SOAP UI the webservice responds `"Message is incomplete. No Sender found"` so it seems that the `^` must be present.

Any idea of how to put `^` in the URL without giving an exception?

Comment: The charachter `^` is actually unwise to use in URIs according to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-2.4.3

Comment: @JoelJonsson The issue here is that the end-point webservice is not developed by us so I have to stick with that url by the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` character is not allowed in URL, probably SOAPUI is encoding the URL for you. I think the case representation is importat for URL escape characters try with uppercase `%5E` instead of lowercase `%5e`.

EDIT:

I just make a try configuring a TCP monitor on my localhost and making a SOAP request from SOAPUI to `http://localhost:8091?type=entry&version=1.0&Sender.Service=SenderService&Interface=sampleurl/ABC^ServiceRequest`. In the TCP monitor I see `%5E` instead of `^` so it seems that SOAPUI is encoding the URL properly, you can see this in the image below:

[image]

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have also tried this but it throws another error and I don't know if escaping ^ as uppercase is working right now... what a headache of application! Anyways, upvote for your time and if after I solve the current problem this works I will accept your answer :)

Comment: I make a try with TCP monitor an seems that the correct aprox is %5E, take a look on the answer which I just edited. Thanks for the upvote and good luck finding the solution :).